# How to inject dependencies into Spark main method?

Tags: java, apache-spark, dependency-injection, guice, amazon-emr

I'm using Spark and EMR for a project. I have a class that will use the AWS SDK to launch a cluster with a JAR file with the Spark Job.

My current problem is, I have some dependencies that I would like to inject using Guice for the Spark Job. With my limited understanding of Guice, I believe this is only possible if I create an instance of the Spark Job (and bind the static values used by `main()` within the constructor). Plus, it doesn't really make sense to me to do this since `main()` is the entry point for the SparkJob...

Is this a problem? If so, what is a workaround?

Edit: perhaps I can just call the constructor from within `main()`?

Comment: Could you post your code?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't as it's internal, but I can try to write some pseudocode later. I think I figured out the solution though, not sure quite yet